# Jackson trying to deserialize json into a List of typed objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson to deserialize a property on a object which is a List of typed objects. and i get the following error when I try to do it

> Can not instantiate value of type `[map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]` from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method

So far I have the following but it does not seem to work.

```
Terms.class

@JsonDeserialize(as=JsonMapDeserializer)
private List<ObjectA> results = null;   //ommitted getter and setters
```

My Deserializer class is as follows.

```
public class JsonMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<ObjectA>> {

List<ObjectA> retMap = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();

TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>[]>  typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>[]>() {};

@Override
public List<ObjectA> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    //read the json string into the map
    HashMap<String, String>[] maps = mapper.readValue(parser, typeRef); 
    if(maps != null) {
        for(HashMap<String, String> map : maps) {               
            ObjectA result = new ObjectA("id", map.get("id"));
            retMap.add(result);
        }
    }

    return retMap;
}

}
```

and I am using simple modules to add the deserializer as follows

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("safety", Version.unknownVersion());
        module.addDeserializer(List.class, new JsonMapDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
```

The JSON string that I end up trying to desrialize is as follows

```
"SearchTerms":{"results":[{id":"1010","checked":"true"}] // there are other fields I have just omitted them
```

When I run the code to deserialize I get the following stack trace

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.model.search["searchTerm1"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:379)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:268)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:244)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:33)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:104)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1294)
at com.az.rd.ke.json.JsonColumnMapDeserializer.deserialize(JsonColumnMapDeserializer.java:41)
at com.az.rd.ke.json.JsonColumnMapDeserializer.deserialize(JsonColumnMapDeserializer.java:27)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.
```

From looking at the stack trace and debugging because my module has been set up as follows

```
module.addDeserializer(List.class, new JsonMapDeserializer());
```

When deserializing it seems to complain as soon as it gets to the first property in my object which is a list, because `searchTerm1` which it complains about is only a list of strings.

Can anybody please advise on how I would deserialize a list of typed objects, or how I could add the deserializer correctly. If I changed the `adddeserializer` method to

```
module.addDeserializer(List<ObjectA>.class, new JsonMapDeserializer());
```

it has compiler issues because the deserializer class is typed as `List<ObjectA>`.

Answer (score 0):

it does look like the object you want to deserialise is a `Map<String, List<Map<String,String>>>`, not a `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Maybe try that instead?